# Simplest way to wrap multiple elements with a parent container in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to wrap the `header`, `main` and `footer` elements in a container `div` created with JavaScript. In other words I want to insert a container div as a direct child of the `body` element but have it wrap all of `body`'s children.

```css
@import url( 'https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css' );

::selection {
  background-color: #fe0;
  color: #444;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

header, main, footer {
  height: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  background-color: #444;
}

p {
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
}

.container {
  height: 90%;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>

    <header>
      <p>header</p>
    </header>
    
    <main>
      <p>main</p>
    </main>
    
    <footer>
      <p>footer</p>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

I've seen this done with single elements utilizing `replaceChild()`, but not with multiple elements as is here. **I would like to not use jquery here.**

Ideas?

Comment: @Flame2057 only for learning reasons. I want to get pretty heavy into JS and maybe build a framework. I'll need to know how to do stuff like this in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Create a new div
- Obtain a nodeList with `document.querySelectorAll`
- Use `Array#forEach.call` on the nodeList to iterate through it and append each element to the newly created div
- Append the new div to the body:

The code would look something like this:

```
var newElem = document.createElement('div')
newElem.textContent = 'newElem';

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('header, main, footer'), function(c){
  newElem.appendChild(c);
});
document.body.appendChild(newElem);
```

[JSBIN here](http://jsbin.com/wafugiquke/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: This works well. Thank you. Here it is with `.container` class added: https://jsfiddle.net/gqvuL2fj/

Comment: Glad you found it useful, and thanks for your updated link