# Moving multiple elements into new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I want to move label, input and span elements inside the new div.

The structure is like this

```
<label for="" class="">First name</label>
<input id="fxb_8f3aee" class="form-control" type="text" value="" maxlength="255" placeholder="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

I want the label,input and span elements inside a new div like this

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="" class="">First name</label>
   <input id="fxb_8f3aee" class="form-control" type="text" value="" maxlength="255" placeholder="">
   <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I am able to move label inside the div using the following code

```
var el = $('.form-control');
$(el).add($(el).prev('label')).wrapAll('<div class="form-group"/>');
```

How can I also move the span element next to the `input element (class = form-control)` inside the `form-group class div`

**I dont want to move all the elements. The HTML structure has few other hidden input and label elements. I just want to move the label above input[class=form-control] and the span below input[class=form-control] into a new div**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
var el = $('.form-control');
el.add(el.prev('label')).add(el.next('span')).wrap('<div class="form-group">');
```

```css
.form-group {background-color:pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"></script>
<label for="" class="">First name</label>
<input id="fxb_8f3aee" class="form-control" type="text" value="" maxlength="255" placeholder="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true">span</span>
```

There is no need for wrapping your `el` with `$()`, as it is already a jQuery object. Also, you can use the simpler `.wrap()` instead of `.wrapAll()` which is intended to be used for a nested wrapping of more than one layers. In your case you only wrap with *one* layer (`<div class="form-group">`).

Answer (score 0):

You can move all of the elements into the div with this code:

```js
var newElem = document.createElement('div')

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('label, input, span'), function(c){
  newElem.appendChild(c);
});
document.body.appendChild(newElem);
```

1. Create a new div
2. Obtain a nodeList with `document.querySelectorAll`
3. Use `Array#forEach.call` on the nodeList to iterate through it and append each element to the newly created div

This is adapted from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034782/simplest-way-to-wrap-multiple-elements-with-a-parent-container-in-javascript).

Comment: I dont want to move all the elements. The HTML structure has few other hidden input and label elements. I just want to move the the label above input[class=form-control] and the span below input[class=form-control] into a new div

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can follow my JS code:

The HTML Code (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <label id="lbl" for="" class="">First name</label>
  <input id="fxb_8f3aee" class="form-control" type="text" value="" maxlength="255" placeholder="">
  <span id="spn" class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

  <div class="form-group"></div>


  <!-- Add Your Custom Script Here -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/myScript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the `'myScript.js'` file:

```
const labelNode = document.getElementById('lbl');
const inputNode = document.getElementById('fxb_8f3aee');
const spanNode = document.getElementById('spn');
const divNode = document.getElementsByClassName('form-group')[0];

divNode.appendChild(labelNode);
divNode.appendChild(inputNode);
divNode.appendChild(spanNode);
```

Keep in mind that, don't try to insert all the nodes at once. Insert each node step by step. I think it is easy to understand my code.

Comment: You code is easy to understand but adding id's to everything is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var el = $('.form-control');
let nextSpan = $("#fxb_8f3aee").next('span');
$(el).add($(el).prev('label')).wrapAll('<div class="form-group"/>');
$(el).add(nextSpan).wrapAll('<div class="form-group"/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<label for="" class="">First name</label>
<input id="fxb_8f3aee" class="form-control" type="text" value="" maxlength="255" placeholder="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Comment: You are creating 2 form-groups. OP only want 1